# сертификат letsencrypt не работает

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

Создаю сертификат letsencrypt

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d domain.ml -d www.domain.ml
```

Пишет что все прошло успешно, при проверке на `ssllabs.com` выдает **F**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: английским по белому же написано что серт отозван и к нему нет доверия

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev тут скорее вопрос в том, кто и почему отозвал свежевыпущенный сертификат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш сертификат действительно отозван:

```
bash$ openssl ocsp -url http://r3.o.lencr.org/ -issuer ~/tmp/lets-encrypt-r3.pem -serial 0x04e37fd795e8e35664a83a6c3804dc908e45 -text

OCSP Response Data:
    OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
    Response Type: Basic OCSP Response
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Responder Id: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
    Produced At: Aug 23 06:30:00 2021 GMT
    Responses:
    Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha1
      Issuer Name Hash: 48DAC9A0FB2BD32D4FF0DE68D2F567B735F9B3C4
      Issuer Key Hash: 142EB317B75856CBAE500940E61FAF9D8B14C2C6
      Serial Number: 04E37FD795E8E35664A83A6C3804DC908E45
    Cert Status: revoked
    Revocation Time: Aug 23 06:30:00 2021 GMT
```

Получается, сертификат был выпущен в 5:29, а в 6:30 отозван. Может быть, между 5:29 UTC и 6:30 UTC вы ещё раз запросили сертификат? При запросе обновления сертификата Certbot отзывает прежний сертификат.